# How to use JUnit's @Rule annotation with Scala Specs2 tests?

Tags: scala, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, specs2

In our project we use Scala Specs2 together with Selenium.
I'm trying to implement screenshot-on-failure mechanism "[in a classic way (link)](https://gist.github.com/banterCZ/2594935)" for my tests, using JUnit annotations, but, the rule doesn't called on test failure at all.

The structure of the test is as follows:

```
class Tests extends SpecificationWithJUnit{

      trait Context extends LotsOfStuff {
        @Rule
        val screenshotOnFailRule = new ScreenshotOnFailRule(driver)
      }

      "test to verify stuff that will fail" should {
        "this test FAILS" in new Context {
         ...
      }
}
```

The ScreenshotOnFailRule looks like this:

```
class ScreenshotOnFailRule (webDriver: WebDriver) extends TestWatcher {

  override def failed(er:Throwable, des:Description) {
    val scrFile = webDriver.asInstanceOf[TakesScreenshot].getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE)
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(s"/tmp/automation_screenshot${Platform.currentTime}.png"))
  }
}
```

I understand that probably it doesn't work now because the tests aren't annotated with @Test annotation.
Is it possible to annotate the Specs2 tests with JUnit @Rule annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584811/how-to-use-junits-temporaryfolder-in-scalas-specs2-tests) it seems as if JUnit Rules aren't supported. But you could try to make use of the `AroundExample` trait:

```
import org.specs2.execute.{AsResult, Result}
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.specification.AroundExample

class ExampleSpec extends Specification with AroundExample {

  // execute tests in sequential order
  sequential

  "The 'Hello world' string" should {
    "contain 11 characters" in  {
      "Hello world" must have size (10)
    }

   // more tests..
  }

  override protected def around[T](t: => T)(implicit ev: AsResult[T]): Result = {
    try {
      AsResult.effectively(t)
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => {
        // take screenshot here
        throw e
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. Looks like MyNotifier doesn't got registered for failure - exampleFailure method isn't called when test fail. Any suggestions please? Can you please try it on your machine?

Comment: Note that you must fully qualify the reference to your Notifier in the arguments for report. For instance, if your spec and your Notifier are both placed in the package `mytest` you need to write `args.report(notifier = "mytest.MyNotifier")`. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, now i see some progress. Event "specStart" works correctly ("specEnd" not...). But, still there is some issues I don't understand:
1) All my tests executed twice. First "normal" run and in the second run it looks like the notifier (MyNotifier) executes them. 2) How do I find the needed event? In my case, i want to "catch" test failure event, and exampleError is, well, example :)

Comment: Your tests aren't executed twice. Your notifier will only get notified whenever the respective event happens. So in order to get notified when a failure happens, you only need to implement `exampleFailure`. Don't be confused by the name, since this is specs terminology.

Comment: If in doubt, check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/edgarmueller/4a230e213385c061a010).

Comment: Oh, nice. When i'm trying the code in the Gist it works correctly. But, it has strange behaviour - i have bunch of tests and the logging i do with exampleFailure/specStart/specEnd appears only in the end of the test class and not per test (or sub-test for that matter). Any ideas please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67031/discussion-between-user3567830-and-stas-s).